# Lift & shift migration with minimal changes

Tags: migration, cloud

In Lift and Shift migration strategy there is minimal or no change. Can someone provide an example for "minimal change".

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A minimal change is not really an objective measure and can be minimal in contrast to the efforts involved when considering the polar opposite:  a greenfield migration.

Some lift and shift scenarios power down complete 19’’ racks,  move the equipment and power back on everything as it was.

Others only lift and shift servers, but those servers  move to new 19’’ cabinets where there are new power distribution units and new network switches. The environment changes and rack placement of the servers can change during the move. But still no configuration changes in OS and/or application settings are necessary. The network settings don’t change.

Slightly more invasive are server moves when after the move and powering on a sysadmin needs to log in to the server and make (small) OS changes.

Whether  those required  changes, especially when they concern changes in IP addresses are considered *minimal* or not is certainly a matter of opinion.